# javascript using hover to change color

Tags: javascript, hover

Hey im trying to change color of "Hello" when i hover over it. So far i cant get it to work and when i look at the console i get "ReferenceError: hover is not defined" same goes for "out". How do i fix this and is this the only issue? thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script>
    var $Osc = {
hover: function(event){
    ("style", "background-color:blue;")
},
out: function(event){
    ("style", "background-color:white;")
}

}
var $Osc = document.getElementById("change");
hover.addEventListener("mouseover", $Osc.hover, false);
out.addEventListener("mouseout", $Osc.out, false);

     </script>


</head>
<body>
 <div id="change"onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="out(this)">
     Hello
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no place you have defined `hover` and `out`. You need to change your code this way:

```
var $OscElement = document.getElementById("change");
$OscElement.addEventListener("mouseover", $Osc.hover, false);
$OscElement.addEventListener("mouseout", $Osc.out, false);
```

You are also overwriting the `$0sc` as the current element, which causes a problem. Finally, either execute the whole script after the page load or put the script after the elements.

You don't need the `onmouse` events on the element, which can be removed.

Finally, the way you are setting the CSS is totally wrong. You need to use the `event.target` for the current element.

The fixed code would be:

```js
var $Osc = {
  hover: function(event) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  },
  out: function(event) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }

}
var $OscElement = document.getElementById("change");
$OscElement.addEventListener("mouseover", $Osc.hover, false);
$OscElement.addEventListener("mouseout", $Osc.out, false);
```

```html
<div id="change">
  Hello
</div>
```

Ultimately, the whole thing can be easily achieved using CSS, not sure why you want JavaScript to do this:

```css
#change {
  background: white;
}
#change:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="change">
  Hello
</div>
```